# The Music Fans proposal is going to move into beta!

Tags: discussion, area51

The [Music Fans proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) has reached 200 committers, meaning that it will be launched as a new SE site soon!

Comment: Congratulations! Great step forward!  ☺

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Music Fan SE is now live.](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It has been a little quiet around there the last couple of days - if you are thinking of checking it out, now might be a good time!